# "getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution" in RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, pop3

I'm trying to retrieve emails from gmail using pop3 to my rails applicaiton. I get the error - "getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution" when i try to retrieve the email.

the weird thing is, it works when i try it at home but not at my university. i'm guessing it has something to do with the internet connection.

please help!

Comment: I just had a similar problem - was able successfully to use dig and host to determine the hostname - but the running ruby application's logs were spitting out thousands of these failure messages. Restarting the service fixed it - just not happy with classifying that as anything other than a temporary fix. :-/

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem just started getting this error out of the blue in a RoR application that connects to an API using a RestClient running on a local virtual machine using Vagrant that I have as a development environment.

The only thing that fixed the issue was simply restarting my virtual machine. Just done a vagrant down & up command, then rackup and back in the game.

Answer (score 1):

This generally means you aren't getting a response from DNS.  Your university connection is probably behind a proxy preventing you from directly accessing the Internet.  If so, this proxy must be specified in your code.  Check your POP3 library documentation, or failing that, you may be able to use a library like socksify that redirects TCP connections through your SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You may be directed through a proxy server. Set up a new connection ,set up your college settings,restart your server and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

ssh into your server and check if the machine is able to resolve the domain.

`ping <your_site>` should resolve the domain name to IP.

If its not resolving correctly, then there is some problem in your hosting service.

**quick fix**: You can manually map domain-to-ip in the `etc/hosts` file of your server.